# What would my return value be in order to continue from a previous statement?

Tags: c, return

to make things a little cleaner i only included the + , - operators in this calc.
with the help of others from this board i was finally able to get my numbers to add/subtract consecutively.

My Problem(s):

From my understanding, anything i input besides a + , - should give "Not an operation of the function. Try again".

The first error i run into is that i have to input something other than +, - twice in order to get that message. (shouldn't once be enough since it's the first thing being recognized by the computer?).
And after that, what would my return value have to in order to go back to were i previously left off?

> ```
> EX:
> 0 + 3
> = 3
> -1
> =2
> Fsgdf
> Not an operation of funcation. try again
> +1
> =3
> ```

```
     #include <stdio.h>
    /* int askYN (const char *prompt) */
    double process (void);

    int main ()
    {
        int done = 0;

        while (!done)
    {
    double result;
    result = process();
    printf("Final Result = %f\n", result);

    }

    return 0;
}

double process (void)
{
    double orig;
    double new_number;
    char symbol;

    orig = 0;
    printf("%.2f", orig);
    while(1==scanf(" %c", &symbol))
    {
    scanf("%lf", &new_number);

            if(symbol=='+') {
                orig+= new_number;
                printf("Result is %.2f \n", orig);
                }
            else if(op=='-') {
                result-=num; 
                printf("The new result is %6.2f", result);
                }
            else {
            printf("Not an operation of the function.\nTry again.");
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this your final code? what `op` and `num` in your `process` function?

Comment: you scan twice, that's why you have to input twice to get a response. what's unclear to you?

Comment: The stack knows where to jump back to once this function is done. If you don't necessarily have to return something you can make your function `void process(void){..}`

Comment: it's not my final code but i'm still working on it.
i was under the impression that since its (void) i could just leave it like that and not to have to put the op and num in the func?
It compiles fine except i get a warning which states theres no return value for process function

Comment: Tim C.   if i do that then it tells me its not an allowed function in main.
mangusta i understand its because i have to scan twice. but doesn't it read the first scanf and make the decision of what to do from there and THEN do addition/subtr with the number?

Comment: Jay. hmmm thats a cool idea. would i be able to insert a scanf in one of the if statements?
EX: 
if(symbol=='+') {
scanf("%lf", &new_number);
orig+= new_number;
printf }

Comment: @user3491518 look my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do like first check the symbol (+/-) then if any symbol from above then go for other scanf to get number`. If not any above symbol then you give error message.

For example

```
while(1==scanf(" %c", &symbol))
{

    if(symbol=='+' || symbol=='-') 
    {
        scanf("%lf", &new_number);
        //your arithmetic operation according symbol
    }
    else
    {
        //your error message
    }
}
```

Comment: Very very cool! it really amazes me how such adjustments in a code can give a completely new input. THANK YOU! god i need so much practicing to do!!!